# AngularJS directive working together unexpectly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created an an angularjs directive for a drop-down box, The directive is working fine but the issue is that when I replicate the directive then both are working simultaneously opening, selection and closing

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Controller">
    <drop-down></drop-down>
    <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
    <drop-down></drop-down>
</div>
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6f9dfavg/)**

Comment: [https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive)

Comment: Both were using same scope. You must use isolated scope in that case

Comment: Please post your code *here*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `scope:true` to your directive:

```
app.directive('dropDown', function ($parse, $document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:true,
        ...
    }
});
```

By specifying `scope: true`, each directive will create its own child scope that inherits from the parent scope, and will not affect each other.

If you don't specify `scope:true`, then each directive is sharing data from parent scope (in this case, parent scope is the controller's scope), which explains why the behavior of both directives are linked.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gngCcVVgh2lGpwFh0qsS?p=preview)

Comment: Today I have discuss with my team lead regarding with the drop-down list with bootstrap that you have created yesterday, but what he said is because since we are using a client framework which uses their own css, we cant use bootstrap which will override many components. He asked me to resolve the issue which the component I have created, I have created a separate SO for that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426932/angularjs-function-in-parent-directive-not-getting-called-from-transcluded-html. Can you please help me on this

Answer (score 3):

Just add `scope: {}` in your directive [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6f9dfavg/2/)

Answer (score 3):

It's because both the `directives` are in the same `controller`. So the directive is using same scope.

In that case, you must either use isolated scope to create separate scope for the directives. Or must wrap the multiple directives with different controllers.

In your directive code: add `scope: {}`

```
app.directive('dropDown', function ($parse, $document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: ['?ngModel'],
        scope: {},
        template: ...

   }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gqwmqh1s/)