# angularjs function in parent directive not getting called from transcluded html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have created a dropdown list like feature using angualrjs directive, The directive is working somewhat but not in correct way I expected.
Following are the issues which I am facing.

- The drop-down list alignment is correct for static but not for dynamic
- I am not able to select any of the option list since `getValue` function which I have defined in the parent directive is not been invoked from the trancluded directive

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

My code is as given below

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/S49kxcIRoxDyhbU7wXKI?p=preview)**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  Static
  <grant-parent ng-model="grand1">
    <parent label="Parent1" value="12">
      <child value="56" label="Child1">Child1</child>
      <child value="57" label="Child2">Child2</child>
    </parent>
    <parent label="Parent1" value="13">
      <child value="58" label="Child3">Child3</child>
      <child value="59" label="Child4">Child4</child>
    </parent>
  </grant-parent>


  Dynamic
  <grant-parent ng-model="grand2">
    <parent ng-repeat="parent in data" label="{{parent.parentName}}" value="{{parent.parentId}}">
      <child ng-repeat="child in parent.childrens" label="{{child.name}}" value="{{child.id}}">{{child.name}}</child>
    </parent>
  </grant-parent>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transclusion and `ng-repeat` have caused me headaches, and I thought it would be challenging, but the solution proves quite simple:

**Remove the DOM manipulation from your link function and do the transclusion in the template!**

I.e. `<div ng-transclude></div>` in the template of the `parent` and remove this line: `elm.find('div').replaceWith(transclude())`.

Forked plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/UGp6D29yxnu0uJwD1BM2?p=preview

---

Now the markup comes out a bit different, the wrapper `<div>` still exists. Although there seems to be no visual difference, this may not be what you want. I do not think there is a sane way to get around this, so I would suggest altering the layout a bit: Why don't you place the children *inside* the parent `<li>`, e.g. as:

```
<li>
    <b><a href='#' ng-click='getValue(optGroupLabel,optGroupValue)'>{{optGroupLabel}}<span class='value'>{{optGroupValue}}</span></a></b>
    <div ng-transclude></div><!-- the div is now inside the li -->
</li>
```

This works in the plunker, but the markup is still invalid (`<li>` within `<div>`).

The best solution is to wrap the children in their own `<ul>`, i.e.:

```
<li>
    <b><a href='#' ng-click='getValue(optGroupLabel,optGroupValue)'>{{optGroupLabel}}<span class='value'>{{optGroupValue}}</span></a></b>
    <ul ng-transclude></ul><!-- The div is replaced with ul -->
</li>
```

This does *not* work in the plunk as it is, but should work with a little CSS tweaking.

---

**Concerning `getValue`** You have gotten wrong how isolated scopes and transclusion work. The `grandParent` directive defines the `getValue` method in its isolated scope. The transcluded things (the `parent` and `child` directives) get the *outer* scope, i.e. the scope of the `MainCtrl`. A solution is to move `getValue()` to the `MainCtrl`.

A better solution would be to pass a callback to the descendants of the grandparent, e.g. as `scope: { assignValue: '&' }`. But this solution cannot be implemented for the code in its current form because the grandparent does not directly include its children, so it cannot pass arguments to them.

The final solution - copied from the comments: move `getValue` to the *controller* of grandParent, have the parent and children require the grandparent and call that function. See http://plnkr.co/edit/pS9SspLaoPlqoWMYr8I0?p=preview

Comment: now dynamic drop-down alignment is fine, but why we cant access the getValue function , through which we can select the option list

Comment: The directives have isolated scope which does not define the `getValue` function.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about `getValue` in the question, I 'll come back to it - the reason is the isolated scope as mentioned above though.

Comment: how about putting isolated controller for the grandParent and putting the getValue  funtcion

Comment: I cant move that function to MainCtrl, how about using factories....Don't know what to do

Comment: Another solution is to move `getValue` to the *controller* of grandParent, have the parent and children `require` the grandparent and call that function.

Comment: I have moved to grandParent controller like what you have said ....but not getting worked....Am I missing anything... http://plnkr.co/edit/r2FgjhJarEDgvHACfnZZ?p=preview

Comment: So what's the difference between `$scope.getValue` `this.getValue` in controller, even we have to consider that also

Comment: `this` adds the method to the controller; it is needed because the dependent directives get a reference to the controller, not the scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74407/discussion-between-alex-man-and-nikos-paraskevopoulos).